# how to disable scrollviewer automatic moving of scrollviewer in XAML Phone Application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

How can I make my `scrollviewer` not to move automatically when I move
and release it with mouse

I know it is the normal behavior, I need to make it keep its current horizontal `offset` when I release mouse.

Comment: @DanielBross what's the bounty for? do you want an answer to this question or your own? They don't look like they're the same questions...

Answer (score 2):

You need to make [IsScrollInertiaEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.isscrollinertiaenabled.aspx) false.

```
scrollviewer.IsScrollInertiaEnabled = false;
```

Sources: [IsScrollInertiaEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.isscrollinertiaenabled.aspx) , [Inertia Mechanics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .